# Unable to configure multi tenant Azure ad with Identity server 4

Tags: flutter, .net-core, azure-active-directory, identityserver4, multi-tenant

I am having flutter mobile app and using identity server 4. Now I need to configure Azure Ad with identity server. In our scenario we have different customers having there own azure ad setup and we have a common login page.
Now, How can I configure multiple azure ad with identity server for different organizations having the fact each organization has its own AAD setup.
It would great if someone can share workflow details about how can we do this with flutter app.

Answer (score 0):

•   You can surely configure Azure AD as an external identity provider in Identity Server 4 by adding appropriate ***authentication handlers for Azure AD in your Identity Server 4** as below. Please do **ensure that an application is registered in your client’s Azure AD for your Identity Server 4 with the redirect URI as ‘http://localhost:5000/signin-aad’(you can find it in the ‘Startup’ class in the ‘ConfigureServices’ method in your Identity Server 4 portal)***. Kindly enter the required details of the **application registered, i.e., application ID, tenant ID, etc. in the below mentioned authentication handler for Azure AD** and accordingly update it in the Identity Server 4: -

```
 services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddOpenIdConnect("aad", "Azure AD", options =>
    {
        options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;
        options.SignOutScheme = IdentityServerConstants.SignoutScheme;

        options.Authority = "https://login.windows.net/<Directory (tenant) ID>";
        options.ClientId = "<Your Application (client) ID>";
        options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
        options.CallbackPath = "/signin-aad";
        options.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/signout-callback-aad";
        options.RemoteSignOutPath = "/signout-aad";
        options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            NameClaimType = "name",
            RoleClaimType = "role"
        };
    });
```

Kindly find the below application registration details snapshot for your reference. Once done, then you will be able to see the **‘Azure AD’** login tab on your **Identity Server 4 login portal under external login section**. Through this option, a registered Azure AD user from your client side will be able to login to the Identity Server 4 with Azure AD credentials: -

[image: Application registration]
[image: Azure AD external login]

Please do ensure that basically it is considered that **Identity Server 4 is configured on ASP .Net Core build versions. Thus, the authentication handlers accordingly. Likewise, you can configure multiple authentication handlers in your Identity Server 4 for multiple Azure AD tenants and ensure that external identity login is enabled for every tenant**. Please find the below link for more information: -

***https://www.ashleyhollis.com/how-to-configure-azure-active-directory-with-identityserver4***